# Formula to calculate the sum of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I want the formula to calculate the sum of following pattern given `n`  and `m`:

$$^nC_1  *  ^mC_1$$
$$+^nC_1  *  ^mC_2$$
$$...$$
$$+^nC_1  *  ^mC_m$$

$$+^nC_2  *  ^mC_1$$
$$+^nC_2  *  ^mC_2$$
$$...$$
$$+^nC_2  *  ^mC_m$$

$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$

$$+^nC_n  *  ^mC_1$$
$$+^nC_n  *  ^mC_2$$
$$...$$
$$+^nC_n  *  ^mC_m$$

Thus if `n=2` and `m=3`, I want the formula to calculate the sum of all these:

$$^2C_1  *  ^3C_1$$
$$+^2C_1  *  ^3C_2$$
$$+^2C_1  *  ^3C_3$$

$$+^2C_2  *  ^3C_1$$
$$+^2C_2  *  ^3C_2$$
$$+^2C_2  *  ^3C_3$$

$$=21$$

if `n=3` and `m=3`, then the sum of all these nine items:

$$^3C_1  *  ^3C_1$$
$$+^3C_1  *  ^3C_2$$
$$+^3C_1  *  ^3C_3$$

$$+^3C_2  *  ^3C_1$$
$$+^3C_2  *  ^3C_2$$
$$+^3C_2  *  ^3C_3$$

$$+^3C_3  *  ^3C_1$$
$$+^3C_3  *  ^3C_2$$
$$+^3C_3  *  ^3C_3$$

$$=49$$

So, what can be a general formula through which I can directly get the answer for this pattern given `n` and `m` values.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by "all possible ways of putting n and m items together"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I did not explain it properly. I have updated the question. I want the formula to calculate the pattern in the question.

Comment: Can you write your question using standard mathematical notation, including $\sum$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sums of products can be broken up into the product of two sums, each of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{m} \binom {m}{k} =2^m-1$, so the answer to your question is $(2^m-1)(2^n-1)$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For those experiencing brain clog, that's $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m} \binom {m}{k}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{k}\right)$$

I know a bunch of people who won't see it. Here's lookin' at you, kid.